# All binary permutations of a fixed length in C

Tags: c, arrays, binary

I have searched over this topic, but could not find. The problem is: Given an integer `n`, generate an array containing all `2^n` combinations of `0` and `1`.

For example, when `n = 2`, we should get `{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1 }}`. I found that `itertools.product` does this in `Python` with the parameter `repeat` (but my employer wants it strictly in `C`).

I need that the code will be suited for `n = 24, 25` cases (and will be ***fast enough*** - this is my employer's demand).

Further, I have another question. Does `C` have anything similar to `Generator` in `Python`?

**EDIT**

I see a lot of *-ve* feedbacks here. I am really sorry for this confusion. Here I try to re-frame my question:

I have an array of `160` elements, of which only `24` (or `25`) are marked (indices of these marked elements are stored in a separate array). I need to take all the `160` elements `2^24` times - each time one or more marked elements will be replaced by its *dual*, and perform some operation (this operation takes `160` elements and yields a binary response each time and I need the XOR of all the responses). How can I efficiently do that?

The manager of the farm I work for does not know other than `C`. So, he wants it to be done in `C`.

*Each element is a 2D array.

**EDIT #2**

May be, I'm still unable to clarify my problem I'm stuck with. I'm working on the basis of the pseudo-code:

```
all_elements = { <collection of elements> };
all_marked_elements = { <collection of 24 marked elements> };
all_combinations = { <all 0, 1 combinations of length 2^24> };

int operation (<160 elements>) {
    ...
    return 0 or 1;
}

x = 0;

foreach (c in all_combinations) {
    e = {};
    for (i >= 0; i <= 23; i=i+1) {
        if (c[i] == 1) {
            append all_marked_elements[i] to e;
        }
    }
    d = get dual of all elements in e; 
    x xor= operation ( <all_elements with e replaced by d>);
}
show x;
```

Comment: This question is two questions. And that's not nice.

Comment: You're asking how to count in binary.

Comment: I wonder who this "employer" really is ...?

Comment: @alk: a... future one, maybe? sounds like an entry-level interview question (if not homework) </ot>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer goes like this.

1. In C, the natural way to deal with an array of [0,1] is by treating them as bits.
2. The 2^24 permutations of 24 bits are precisely the values of unsigned int from 0 to 2^24-1.
3. So the question essentially is how to write the code based on that data structure.

Something like this.

```
int all_elements[160] = { ??? };
int all_marked_elements[24] = { ??? };
unsigned combo;
for (combo = 0; combo < 0x1000000; ++combo) {
  /* you probably want to take a copy of all_elements here */
  for (i = 0; i < 23; ++i) {
    unsigned bit = 1 << i;
    if (combo & bit) {
      int marked_element = all_marked_elements[i];
      /* do something I didn't understand, replacing element by its dual */
    }
    /* now call the operation and do something with the result */
  }
}
```

Comment: *Dual* is something irrelevant here. And, thank you for understanding my needs (huh!).

Comment: My pleasure. You got a lot of downvotes which I don't think were really deserved, because most people didn't understand the question. You'll get better answers if you work at making your questions easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

actually, you only need to look up bits in an integer. if you have 25 bits, your permutations correspond to the bit sequences of all numbers `0<= i < 2^25`, which fits in a simple `unsigned int`. you don't need to "generate" and store these numbers, just use them wherever you need the permutations.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    int i,n=2;
    char arr[500];
    for(i=0;i<pow(2,n);i++)
        printf("%s\n",itoa(i,arr,2));
}
```

Comment: Why the conversion to a character representation?